# Is it useful to call BeginUpdate/EndUpdate with a virtual listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I've got a virtual listview with a few hundreds items in it. I must regularly update le listview by clearing it and then adding the new/updated items to it.

Is it useful to call BeingUpdate and EndUpdate while doing this? I could not notice any visual difference.

Thanks

Comment: No. BeginUpdate() ensures that the ListView won't try to repaint itself when you add an item. Important when you add a lot of them. But in virtual mode, you no longer add items. You modify the VirtualListSize with a single assignment.

Answer (score 2):

There can be a huge advantage to using `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`, if you're changing many items at once.  If you're only adding a single element at a time, there will be no advantage.

That being said, it's typically better to just use [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.addrange.aspx), which allows you to add multiple items in a single call without worrying about `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate`.