# ListView flickering when item is focused

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a ListView in VB.NET 2013 working in VirtualMode that I'm using to display an active log. It works fine, except when I have an item focused outside the visible bounds of the ListView: in this case, when I add an item to the ListView it flickers scrolling to the focused item and then immediatly back to the previous position.

The ListView is also DoubleBuffered using this code:

```
Dim pi As PropertyInfo = ListView1.GetType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic)
pi.SetValue(ListView1, True, Nothing)
```

Also, I found out that when I go to the top of the ListView, it brings me to the focused item, and doesn't go back.

If I try to disable the double buffered mode, a white frame is painted every time I add an item, and this is not acceptable since the log adds a lot of items every second.

Comment: `the log adds a lot of items every second.`  That doesn't sound very user friendly: a user can't read that fast.  Sounds like you are updating the GUI too much, too often.

Comment: I know, but the log is taken from an external source: it's the Android system log. So I don't really have control over the number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ListView1.BeginUpdate()` and `ListView1.EndUpdate()` before and after the focus change(s).

Comment: As long as I know, the BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods are useful only when you're **not** using the VirtualMode. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285507/is-it-useful-to-call-beginupdate-endupdate-with-a-virtual-listview)